Masterkey en parseserver
Estoy dando mantenimiento a un proyecto de parse server, quiero que el administrador del sistema pueda cambiar el password del resto de usuarios, para eso necesito usar la masterkey, encontré esta configuracion en el index.js
APP_ID = 'App';

MASTER_KEY = "claveSecreta";

APP_NAME = "NombreApp";

serverURL = "https://direccion.mx/parse";

intente poner la key en un objeto para luego exportarlo de esta forma:
const appConfig = {
  MASTER_KEY: "claveSecreta",
};

module.exports = appConfig;

luego intento importarla en el archivo donde la necesito así:
const appConfig = require('../index');   

const masterKey = appConfig.MASTER_KEY;

console.log('ESTA ES LA CHIDA ', masterKey );

pero el console.log me dice:
ESTA ES LA CHIDA  undefined

alguien sabe como puedo acceder a la masterkey ????

Para solucionar el problema lo que hice fue:
Instalar dotenv (npm install dotenv), ya que por alguna razón aun cuando la masterkey estaba declarada en el index.js, no podía acceder a ella en ningún otro lugar, declararla en un .env me permitió obtenerla.
En el index hice estos ajustes:
const APP_ID = process.env.APP_ID || 'NombreApp';
const MASTER_KEY = process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MasterKeySecret';
const serverURL = process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://laweb/parse'; 

Con los || me asegure de que, si por alguna razón no puedo obtener el valor desde el .env lo tome desde ahí.
Otra cosas rara que paso es que aun con acceso a la masterkey tuve que sobre escribir el valor en cada función donde la necesitaba, ejemplo:
En la cabecera del archivo donde ocupaba privilegios elevados declare esto
const MASTER_KEY = process.env.MASTER_KEY;
Parse.initialize(APP_ID, null, MASTER_KEY);
Parse.masterKey =  process.env.MASTER_KEY; //acceder a la masterKey desde .env

Aun así, me seguía diciendo que no estaba proporcionando la masterkey, para solucionar eso, declare de nuevo la masterkey en cada función
 //guardar los cambios
          Parse.masterKey = process.env.MASTER_KEY;
          user.save(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(
            (userSaved) => {
              if (itemID == req.session.userId) req.session.user = userSaved;
              console.log("user updated.");
              res.status(200).send("user updated.");
            },
            (errorParse) => {
              console.log("Fail to update user. Error " + errorParse.code + ": " + errorParse.message);
              res.status(500).send("Fail to update user.");
            }
          );

es decir puse esta linea
Parse.masterKey = process.env.MASTER_KEY;

en cada lugar justo antes de usarla, puede que no sea lo mas adecuado, pero funciono y se resolvió un problema que tenia mas de 6 años en producción.
Gracias a todos!!!!
